# Using NUnit with .NET 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, nunit, compatibility

Does NUnit work with .NET 3.5? i've the page says it's for .NET 2.0...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it does.

.Net 3.5 can use .Net 2 binaries.

We use NUnit with our 3.5 projects.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works on .NET 3.5